# Divide a textarea strings into groups depends on blank space

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea

I have a textarea in my html form where user can enter numbers and after the form submit,php will echo sum of the numbers
for example, If I enter

```
1
2
```

it will output,

```
sum is 3
```

My requirement is, if I put blank space(one or more), between each set of devices, it has to process each set of devices separately
for example,

```
1
2

3
4
```

and above should display output as

```
sum is 3
sum is 7
```

But using below code I am getting output like

```
sum is 10
```

My Code:

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="cal-main">
<form  id="form1" name="form1" action=" " method="post" > 

<div class="input">Enter Numbers</div>
<div class="output"><span><textarea class="textarea" name="numbers" ></textarea></span></div>


<div class="submit1">
    <input  id="first_submit" type="submit"  name="first_submit" value="first_submit" />
</div>

</form>


<?php

if (isset($_POST['first_submit']))
{
?>
<textarea onclick="this.select()" name="output_textarea" id="output_textarea" cols="100" rows="25" readonly value="">
<?php
$numbers = $_POST['numbers'];
$digits = explode(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, $numbers); // Favor PHP_EOL (end of line) to avoid cross OS issues
foreach($digits as $digit)
{

  $count = array_sum(explode(PHP_EOL, $digit));
  echo "sum is $count".PHP_EOL;
}
}
?>

</textarea>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

[**PHP FIDDLE SETUP**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dac-bi9)

Comment: Have you tried replacing PHP_EOL with a plain old "\n"? PHP_EOL ist the server side EOL and not client side EOL.

Comment: @Dragony       :yes,if I use `"\n"`, it will just echo each digits

Comment: Obviously it should be "\n\n". Just to be sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `preg_split` and `\r?\n`:

```
$digits = preg_split('#(\r?\n){2,}#',$numbers); //2 or more \r\n (\r optional)
foreach($digits as $key => $digit)
{

    $count = array_sum(preg_split('#\r?\n#', $digit));
    echo "sum is $count".PHP_EOL;
    if($key < count($digits)-1) echo '<br />';
}
```

Output:

```
sum is 3
sum is 7
```

Comment: : Thanks, it worked. If I want to add a space between each final output, how can I add it ? I mean single line space between `sum is 3` and `sum is 7`. I tried adding a echo`"<br>";` after `foreach` function, but it is adding an extra space at beginning also.I dont want to add space at beginning, but a space between each set of output

Comment: @acr See my updated answer - it now adds a `<br />` after each one (except the last)

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers = $_POST['numbers'];

$digits = explode("\n", $numbers); // explode by next line
$sums = array(); // array to put sums in
$i = 0;
foreach($digits as $digit) {
    $digit = trim($digit); // remove next line

    if(is_numeric($digit))
        $sums[$i] += $digit; // sum up
    else
        $i++; // next index (row wasn't number)
}

print_r($sums); 

// Output: Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 7 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_split is more appropriate, though new line could be different on different OS. My solution:

```
function split_new_lines($string){
    return preg_split('/\R/', $string);
}

$input = "
1
2

3
4

5
";

$lines = split_new_lines($input);

$sums = array();
$sum = null;
foreach($lines as $line){
    $line = trim($line);
    if(is_numeric($line))
    {
        if($sum === null)
            $sum = (int)$line;
        else
            $sum += (int)$line;
    }
    else
    {
        if($sum !== null)
            $sums[] = $sum;
        $sum = null;
    }
}
if($sum !== null)
    $sums[] = $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

notice that `PHP_EOL is used to find the newline character in a cross-platform-compatible way`. i have tested your code on in a windows/php 5.4.3 and it works as described above. when i run your fiddle, i get the error.

[image: your code output]